# Cannot display text on image in ASP.Net MVC page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm unable to write any text on an image. I've been trying for the whole day yesterday.
This seem to work in other HTML tool like Plain HTML as the code has been taken from w3schools site [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp) but in Visual Studio ASP.Net MVC it doesn't work.

**It's displaying the text at the bottom of the image, not on the image.**

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container1">
                <img src="~/Content/images/headerBackground.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="bottom-left1">Bottom Left</div>
                <div class="top-left1">Top Left</div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.container1 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;    
}


.bottom-left1 {
    position: absolute;        
    left: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding:

```
  bottom: 10px;
```

inside `.bottom-left1`

Comment: Thanks. it seems to work. But  I need the text to be at the top, not at the bottom. Need I just use bottom: like 100px ?  is it right to increase the bottom : to more than 300px ?  I'm afraid maybe it's going to disrupt other upcoming tag I'll use later.

Comment: You can use  `top: 10px`, it will lower the text 10 pixels from the top.

Comment: Thank you guys. I appreciated that.